# find the height of the mountain

Tags: geometry

I am at an observation tower at sea level . to my north east is a mountain and to the south east is a hill  that is 700 feet high .from my view the mzountain is 52 degrees above the horizon . from the hill the mountain , which due north of it , is 37 degrees above horizon . what is hieght of the mountain ? this seems like a easy problem to crunch trig as in tan(x) but why did the author throw in the parts about the mountain and hill being northeast and southeast ? are we to assume these are equal distances ?

Comment: If it weren't the case that they were both equidistant from your observation tower, I don't think there's enough information to solve.  If we assume they are equidistant from the tower, knowing height of the hill and angle of elevation will let you know distance to the hill.  Using that distance and knowing angle of elevation will let you know height of mountain.  You should of course presumably be assuming the earth is flat and ignore curvature to make calculations easier, especially if this is an intro to Trig class.

Comment: If you're not actually asking for a solution then this is opinion based. We can only guess at the author's intentions.

Comment: gracious thank you for the feedback ..and so quick ! shows again advanced math is for a network like math stack exchange . this problem was posted at a university and was a problem of week ( while ago ) so it does tend to be above regular level . i think u are correct Jmoravitz , its easily solved with two trig equations given two angles , a hieght of observer ( the hill) will only add to the total hieght of mountain , but the distances from the mountain to both observer and hill must be equal .

Comment: so anyone post the drawing solution? is it not just tangent of two given angles with x being distance from hill to observation point & mountain to hill, h , the height of mountain will use  tan (37)= (h-700)/x